# Eigenvalues attribute not outputting in sklearn KernelPCA?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pca

I have the following code:

```
from sklearn.decomposition import KernelPCA
x=[1,2,3,4,5]
y=[6,7,8,9,10]
z=[11,12,13,14,15]
data=pd.DataFrame([x,y,z])
kernelPCA = KernelPCA()
kpca_data = kernelPCA.fit_transform(data)
print(kpca_data)
kpca_eigenvalues = kpca_data.eigenvalues_
```

According to the documentation regarding KernelPCA, `eigenvalues_` is an attribute that can be output. However, I am receiving this error:

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'eigenvalues_'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: your `kernelPCA` is the (fitted) instance of `KernelPCA` and so should have an `eigenvalues_` attribute; the transformed _data_ `kpca_data` should not.

Answer (score 0):

As per BenReiniger's comment, to get eigenvalues use the fitted data and not the transformed data.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).